# Enough + of + [a/an] + noun

Tags: grammar

Enough + of + pronoun is fine as in:

> I had enough of you
>
> I can't get enough of it

Enough + of + determiner (my, the, that, etc.) + noun is also fine

> I had enough of this cake
>
> I can't get enough of your love

**But** is Enough + of + a/an + noun correct/standard?

> That is enough of an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A/an* is an article, which is a determiner.

*Enough of {determiner} {noun}* is of course fine, so *a/an*, being a determiner, is also fine.